# Spring Data @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER) working as select query mode

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I attached below my codes. load children one by one, when i get all parent entities. How to solve it?

[image: parent table]

[image: Child Table]

Parent Entity Class. It has 3 attributes as id, name, and children. children attribute load eagerly. because i need parent object with its children.

```java
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "parent")
    public class Parent {
        @Id
        private int id;

        private String name;

        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
        private List<Child> children;

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public List<Child> getChildren() {
            return children;
        }

        public void setChildren(List<Child> children) {
            this.children = children;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
```

Child Class. It has 3 property such as id, name and parent. parent property load as lazy mode. because i never wants child object with its parent object.

```java
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "child")
    public class Child {
        @Id
        private int id;

        @Column(name = "name")
        private String name;

        @JsonIgnore
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "parent", referencedColumnName = "id")
        private Parent parent;

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public Parent getParent() {
            return parent;
        }

        public void setParent(Parent parent) {
            this.parent = parent;
        }
    }
```

I try to get all parents using below code.

```java
    protected List getAll(){
            EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
            entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
            List<Parent> objects = entityManager.createQuery("Select o from Parent o", Parent.class).getResultList();
            entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
            entityManager.close();
            return objects;
        }
```

I expect only one join query. but hibernate call queries one by one. It getting n+1 query problem.

```
    Hibernate: select parent0_.id as id1_8_, parent0_.name as name2_8_ from parent parent0_
    Hibernate: select children0_.parent as parent3_0_0_, children0_.id as id1_0_0_, children0_.id as id1_0_1_, children0_.name as name2_0_1_, children0_.parent as parent3_0_1_ from child children0_ where children0_.parent=?
    Hibernate: select children0_.parent as parent3_0_0_, children0_.id as id1_0_0_, children0_.id as id1_0_1_, children0_.name as name2_0_1_, children0_.parent as parent3_0_1_ from child children0_ where children0_.parent=?
    Hibernate: select children0_.parent as parent3_0_0_, children0_.id as id1_0_0_, children0_.id as id1_0_1_, children0_.name as name2_0_1_, children0_.parent as parent3_0_1_ from child children0_ where children0_.parent=?
```

Comment: Use join fetch for n+1 problem

Comment: why we manipulate manual quires like this? Why hibernate connot manage these kind of situations. What is mean of FetchType.EAGER ?

Comment: And what you think FetchType.EAGER means? See this https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#fetching-direct-vs-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPA doesn't provide any specification on mapping annotations to select fetch strategy.

Use `JOIN FETCH` to fetch both root entities and their mapped entity/collection in one query which solved N+1 query problem.Like

```
SELECT distinct p FROM Parent p LEFT JOIN FETCH p.children
```

Comment: Your query work working as a single query. But it returns duplicate values. Actually i want to know why that situation cannot manage automatically by hibernate ?

Comment: i remove duplicate values using distinct keyword. now its work fine.

Comment: JPA doesn't provide any specification on mapping annotations to select fetch strategy.  Sorry my bad by mistake removed `distinct` when update my answer. 
(see my edit story :P)

Comment: @Niroshan did you understand  ? join create the Cartesian product of rows from the joined tables.